# Linux PPTP client problems

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, pptp

I recently reinstalled my server from Debian Lenny to Squeeze and ever since the reinstall I'm unable to establish a PPTP connection to a remote site. The remote site is running Windows RRAS PPTP server. The PPTP connection worked from Lenny and works from a Windows client. It doesn't work from the Debian Squeeze server. The config files for PPTP and connection were simply copied over from the old system. The connection establishes and then just disconnects right away.

From syslog:

```
Jul  2 07:55:41 awakening pppd[9633]: pppd 2.4.4 started by root, uid 0
Jul  2 07:55:41 awakening pppd[9633]: using channel 14
Jul  2 07:55:41 awakening pppd[9633]: Using interface ppp80
Jul  2 07:55:41 awakening pppd[9633]: Connect: ppp80 <--> /dev/pts/3
Jul  2 07:55:41 awakening pptp[9636]: anon log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Jul  2 07:55:41 awakening pptp[9643]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Jul  2 07:55:41 awakening pptp[9643]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Jul  2 07:55:41 awakening pptp[9643]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pppd[9633]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x32d026a8> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pptp[9643]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pptp[9643]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pptp[9643]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 24212).
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pptp[9643]: anon log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pptp[9643]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pptp[9643]: anon log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pppd[9633]: Script pptp 193.77.X.X --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 9634), status = 0x0
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pppd[9633]: Modem hangup
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pppd[9633]: Connection terminated.
Jul  2 07:55:42 awakening pppd[9633]: Exit.
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem existed because TSS MSS clamper on the router was disabled on a PPPoE connection.